# Delineate a Subset of Values on a 3D surface plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

This is building on a question previously answered by Rahul recently. I have a particular 3D surface plot on which I wish to delineate where z (the function) is between the corresponding x value and the corresponding y value (i.e., x < z < y OR y < z < x) and where x is between z and y (i.e., z < x < y OR y < x < z). I came up with:

```
Plot3D[-4.53 + 2.67 x + 2.78 y - 1.09 x y, {x, 1.8, 2.6}, {y, 1.8, 2.6}, PlotRange -> {1.7, 2.6}, Ticks -> {{1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6}, {1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6}, {1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6}}, LabelStyle -> Opacity[0], BoxRatios -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, z - x], Function[{x, y, z}, z - y], Function[{x, y, z}, x - y], Function[{x, y, z}, x - z]}, Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, MeshShading -> None, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Rahul helped with the first part in which he used MeshFunctions to show where z is between x and y. I tried to build on that for showing where x is between z and y. The problem is that it appears there is no portion where y < x < z. Perhaps that is true -- that such a set of values does not occur for this plot over its plot range, but perhaps I am incorrectly specifying this. Also, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do MeshShading to shade each of the regions; thus I left it as "None." But ideally, I would uniquely color each part. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Corrected error by adding `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

```
f[x_, y_] = -4.53 + 2.67 x + 2.78 y - 1.09 x y //
    Rationalize // Simplify;

Plot3D[f[x, y],
 {x, 1.8, 2.6}, {y, 1.8, 2.6},
 PlotRange -> {1.7, 2.6},
 PlotPoints -> 101,
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}),
 Ticks ->
  {{1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6},
   {1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6},
   {1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ColorFunction ->
  Function[{x, y, z},
   Piecewise[
    {{Blue, (x < z < y) || (y < z < x)},
     {Red, (z < x < y) || (y < x < z)}},
    Green]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much, Bob Hanlon, for your help on this. I might be confused or maybe I inadvertently gave incorrect information, but the lines your formula drew to make the divisions look incorrect. Take for example the large area defined by the largest green section. Except for a very small portion of this near the lower tip (x and y roughly equal to 1.85 and 1.85), all of this AND most of the blue rectangle above it should be blue, not green, as for the majority of this area, z is between x and y. This is correctly indicated in the division specified in MY formula (with help from Rahul).

Comment: I agree that coloring was wrong. I forgot to turn off the `ColorFunctionScaling`. Corrected above.

Comment: Perfect, Bob Hanlon. Thank you so much. -- Keith